# Entry box text clear when pressed Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm not sure whether this has been asked already or not, but I have multiple entry boxes in which contain a default piece of text. I am not trying to set a default piece of text, I'm trying to remove when the entry box is clicked. I want to be able to remove the default text as soon as the entry box is clicked so the user does not have to do so. I was wondering if someone could share a quick example on how this is done so I can implement.

```
    def removeValue(event):
        self.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        return None

    for i in range(1, numberOfStudents + 1):
        for p in range(0,2):
            self.entry = Entry(self.master)
            if p == 0:
                self.entry.insert(0, 'Enter name of student')
                self.entry.place(x = 10, y = (i * 30) + 26)
                self.entry.bind("<Button-1>", removeValue)
            if p == 1:
                self.entry.insert(0, 'Enter predicted')
                self.entry.place(x = (getWidth(master) - 140), y = (i * 30) + 26)
                self.entry.bind("<Button-1>", removeValue)
```

I have this so far, but only deletes the very last entry boxes text.

Comment: `entry.bind("<Button-1>", function_name)` ?

Comment: How would I go about using this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you've got your default text sorted out, you want to create an Event binding somewhere, with the general format of the comment above, not sure why it's not an answer, because it's right:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.insert(0, "some text")

def some_callback(event): # note that you must include the event as an arg, even if you don't use it.
    e.delete(0, "end")
    return None

e.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)

e.pack()
```

Finally, http://effbot.org is your friend:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

EDIT: Additional info for OP from comment.
If you have multiple entries and you need to clear each one individually, you can simply refer to the widget that called the bound method using

```
event.widget
```

Your callback could then work as follows:

```
def some_callback(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "end")
    return None
```

Comment: For a complete example, don't forget to `pack` the widget.

Comment: Once again, you have a good point, I'll add this for completeness.  +1 for you, keeping me in line today :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought it was going to just be as easy as including it in my For loop. I have multiple entry boxes, I've got it to work, but when I click on an entry box, it'll delete the the text of the last one created. Is there a way I could set it to each individual entry box I create within the loop?

Comment: Yes - see my edit or @Bryan Oakley's answer below, we seem to have added them at roughly the same time.

Comment: I think that `return None` is not necessary.

Comment: re: _"with the general format of the comment above"_ - are you aware answers can appear in a different order at different times? As I read this, there is no "comment above". What comment are you referring to?

Comment: Your "EDIT" section suggests using a dictionary and then says "your callback could then work as follows", but the code that follows doesn't use a dictionary. That is very confusing.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I was referring to a comment on the question itself. Also, the confusion is caused by sloppy editing on my part - I was half way through an unnecessarily complicated solution when I thought of this, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The method called by the event binding is given an event object. This object has a reference to the widget that triggered the event. You can use that to clear the widget:

```
def removeValue(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, 'end')
```