# How to bind a mouse click with a tkinter witdges?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to clear text box as soon as i click on it to write, Please help me to do this

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

fileLable = Text(root, height = 1, width = 26 )
fileLable.insert(INSERT, "this text")
fileLable.grid(row = 0, column = 0,columnspan = 2, padx = (10,0),pady = (3,0))

submit = ttk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = some_method)
submit.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = (10,0), pady = (10,0))

root.mainloop()
```

I know that this one :

```
def some_callback(event): # note that you must include the event as an arg, even if you don't use it.
e.delete(0, "end")
return None
```

So then how I catch this event when it is clicked on the text box to include above code to my main code
Please help thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571635/entry-box-text-clear-when-pressed-tkinter

Comment: @Jonas thanks for help jonas. I have added more details to question. please check and help me if you can

Comment: Have you done any research? Calling functions on a button click is well documented, and there are countless examples on the internet. Deleting the text in a widget is also well documented.

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah I did. but I was getting it when some button clicked. for this I dint found so asked here. If you have any article please let me know. I will be happy to learn more. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this below, bind events `<FocusIn>` and `<FocusOut>`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def delText(event=None):
    fileLable.delete("1.0", END)
 
root = Tk()
fileLable = Text(root, height = 1, width = 26 )
fileLable.insert(INSERT, "this text")
fileLable.grid(row = 0, column = 0,columnspan = 2, padx = (10,0),pady = (3,0))
fileLable.bind("<FocusIn>", delText)
submit = ttk.Button(root, text = "Submit")
submit.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = (10,0), pady = (10,0))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @kevin_mayo. This solved my issue. may I know why we are using `fileLable.bind("<Focusout>",showTheTip)` and any article link to go through

Comment: yeah but it is showing when I type move to other widget

Comment: The question specifically asks about a click.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function when a user clicks in a widget, you can bind to the `<1>` event. The function is passed an argument which contains information about the event, including a reference to the widget that received the event.

To delete all of the text in a text widget, call the `delete` method with the arguments `"1.0"` and `"end"`.

Putting that together, it looks like this:

```
def clearText(event):
    event.widget.delete("1.0", "end")

fileLable.bind("<1>", clearText)
```